# SVN error when trying to commit to remote host

Tags: svn

I'm using svn on OS X, and am able to check items out of the repository of an svn server on my university campus (I am at home). I am now trying to commit files from my local working directory. I use the following command:

```
svn commit -m "First commit" file://hostname.ac.uk/directory/project/
```

where hostname is the same as I use to successfully check out items. However, the following error message is returned:

```
svn: Must give local path (not URL) as the target of a commit
```

It would be worth knowing that I have never committed anything to svn before. I wondered if the message implied that to commit I have to be physically connected to the svn server, i.e. on campus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify your local working directory as the last parameter (`.` if you are already in it). It will know what remote location to commit to by itself.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working now! I didn't realise that svn could 'remember' things like your server location.